# C++ TCP server: FD_ISSET() does not always work in a basic server

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

This is my implementation of a soon-to-be HTTP server.

```
void    Webserv::resetFdSets()
{

    int         fildes;

    FD_ZERO(&to_read);
    FD_ZERO(&to_write);
    max_fd = -1;
    Server_map::iterator it;
    for (it = servers.begin(); it != servers.end(); ++it) //set server sockets to be read
    {
        fildes = it->second.getFd();
        FD_SET(fildes, &to_read);
        if (fildes > max_fd)
            max_fd = fildes;
    }
    std::list<int>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = accepted.begin(); iter != accepted.end(); ++iter) // set client sockets if any
    {
        fildes = (*iter);
        FD_SET(fildes, &to_read);
        FD_SET(fildes, &to_write);
        if (fildes > max_fd)
            max_fd = fildes;
    }
}
```

accept()

```
void    Webserv::acceptConnections()
{

   int         client_fd;
   sockaddr_in cli_addr;
   socklen_t   cli_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

   Server_map::iterator    it;
   for (it = servers.begin(); it != servers.end(); ++it)
   {
       ft_bzero(&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));
       if (FD_ISSET(it->second.getFd(), &to_read)) // if theres data in server socket
       {
           client_fd = accept(it->second.getFd(), reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&cli_addr), &cli_len);
           if (client_fd > 0) // accept and add client
           {
               fcntl(client_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
               accepted.push_back(client_fd);
           }
           else
               throw (std::runtime_error("accept() failed"));
       }
    }
}
```

recv()

```
void    Webserv::checkReadSockets()
{

    char        buf[4096];
    std::string raw_request;
    ssize_t     bytes;
    static int  connections;

    std::list<int>::iterator    it;
    for (it = accepted.begin(); it != accepted.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(*it, &to_read))
        {
            ++connections;
            std::cout << "Connection counter : " << connections << std::endl;
            while ((bytes = recv(*it, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, MSG_DONTWAIT)) > 0)
            {
                buf[bytes] = '\0';
                raw_request += buf;
            }
            std::cout << raw_request << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

send()

```
void    Webserv::checkWriteSockets()
{

   char            buf[8096];
   char            http_success[] = {
       "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
       "Server: This op server\r\n"
       "Content-Length: 580\r\n"
       "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
       "Connection: Closed\r\n\r\n" 
   };

   std::list<int>::iterator it = accepted.begin();
   while (it != accepted.end())
   {
       int cliSock = (*it);
       if (FD_ISSET(cliSock, &to_write))
       {
           int     response_fd = open("hello.html", O_RDONLY);

           int bytes = read(response_fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
           send(cliSock, http_success, sizeof(http_success) - 1, MSG_DONTWAIT); // header
           send(cliSock, buf, bytes, MSG_DONTWAIT); // hello world

           close(cliSock);
           close(response_fd);
        
           it = accepted.erase(it);
       }
       else
           ++it;
   }
}
```

main loop:

```
void    Webserv::operate()
{

   int     rc;

   while (true)
   {
       resetFdSets(); // add server and client fd for select()
       if ((rc = select(max_fd + 1, &to_read, &to_write, NULL, NULL)) > 0) // if any of the ports are active
       {
           acceptConnections(); // create new client sockets with accept()
           checkReadSockets(); // parse and route client requests recv() ...
           checkWriteSockets(); // send() response and delete client
       }
       else if (rc < 0)
       {
           std::cerr << "select() failed" << std::endl;
           exit(1);
       }
   }
}
```

The same code highlighted + Webserv class definition on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/9B8uYumF

For now the algorithm is such:

- reset fd_sets for reading and writing.
- if any of the file descriptors trigger select, we check whether server FD are set, accept connections and store them in a list of ints.
- if any of the client FD are FD_ISSET() to read - we read their request and print it.
- finally, if any of the client FD are ready to receive - we dump an html page in there and close the connection.

While checking all the client descriptors FD_ISSET() returns false 80% of the time when it shouldn't. Hence I cannot get client requests consistently. Strangely enough, it returns true with fd_set for write sockets much more often. Here's a demo with 2 out of 10 successful reads using the above code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSqNm.jpg

I know that the new clients are always accepted because it always enters the if condition in acceptConnections(). In other words, the listen FD are initialized correctly.

edit: Here's how it's initialized:

```
void    Server::init()
{
    if ((listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        throw (std::runtime_error("socket() failed"));
    }
    fcntl(listen_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    int yes = 1;
    setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
    if (bind(listen_fd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr)))
    {
        throw (std::runtime_error("bind() failed"));
    }

    if (listen(listen_fd, 0))
        throw (std::runtime_error("listen() failed"));
}
```

Comment: This is not even remotely close to being a valid HTTP server. You are not parsing the HTTP requests at all, and your HTTP response has an error in it. But regarding the handling of `fd_set`s, you are ignoring the return value of `recv()` to detect disconnects/errors. And the reason why `FD_ISSET` returns true for writability more than readability is simply because sockets are usually in a writable state, it is only when the remote peer’s inbound buffer fills up that they are not in a writable state until the buffer frees up space.

Comment: Your handling of HTTP is all wrong, which is causing the rest of your code to exhibit behavior you are not expecting. Fix your handling of HTTP requests to detect when the requests are actually finished being read (see [RFC 2616 section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4)) before sending the responses, do not rely on `select()` to tell you when to send the responses. That is the wrong logic to use. But since you are using non-blocking sockets, you will need to buffer your responses and let `select()` tell you when you can send the buffers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the answer. I know that it still needs some work, but to parse HTTP requests i need them to actually be read consistently, don't you think? :) Im ignoring the return value deliberately: since the sockets are non-blocking, recv() will return -1 with EAGAIN at some point. So my thinking was read while i can > parse everything that was read > respond, but I guess that won't work.

Comment: you are not resetting `raw_request` for each new client you read from. You are not parsing `raw_request` to know WHEN to stop reading, per the RFC (using a blocking timeout is not the way to go). You are not checking `recv()` for failure/disconnect. Any read error other than `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` (which are not always the same value on all platforms) needs to have the client socket closed and removed from the `accepted` list immediately. Your whole `checkWriteSockets()` handling is wrong and error prone. Even before fixing the HTTP stuff, your basic TCP handling needs some more work.

Comment: I would suggest changing your `accepted` list to hold objects, where each object has a socket descriptor and 2 `string` buffers, one for inbound and one for outbound. Whatever data `recv()` returns goes in the inbound buffer, and gets parsed for requests. For each *complete* request, remove it from the inbound buffer, process it, and put a response in the outbound buffer. Check `select()` for writability only for clients with a non-empty outbound buffer. When `select()` reports a client is writable, send and remove data from that client’s outbound buffer until it is clear or `send()` fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, this is very helpful! It's a bit annoying that the data has to be parsed live, but it's great that you've pointed me to the right direction.